# What is the meaning of template<> with empty angle brackets in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<>
class A{
//some class data
};
```

I have seen this kind of code many times.
what is the use of `template<>` in the above code?
And what are the cases where we need mandate the use of it?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`template<>` tells the compiler that a template specialization follows, specifically a **full specialization**. Normally, `class A` would have to look something like this:

```
template<class T>
class A{
  // general implementation
};

template<>
class A<int>{
  // special implementation for ints
};
```

Now, whenever `A<int>` is used, the specialized version is used. You can also use it to specialize functions:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T t){
  // general
}

template<>
void foo<int>(int i){
  // for ints
}

// doesn't actually need the <int>
// as the specialization can be deduced from the parameter type
template<>
void foo(int i){
  // also valid
}
```

Normally though, you shouldn't specialize functions, as [simple overloads are generally considered superior](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm):

```
void foo(int i){
  // better
}
```

---

And now, to make it overkill, the following is a **partial specialization**:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class B{
};

template<class T1>
class B<T1, int>{
};
```

Works the same way as a full specialization, just that the specialized version is used whenever the second template parameter is an `int` (e.g., `B<bool,int>`, `B<YourType,int>`, etc).

Comment: +1 Good answer! Maybe you should add that this is a full template specialization. Even though.. with one template parameter, there's no partial specialization possible anyway.

Comment: This is also useful for defining type traits.

Comment: @Xeo: I wish downvoters would give a comment, anonymous or not (or at least the first of them).

Comment: @Xeo: It might make sense to add "why one would need full template specialization." I believe the only useful scenario is Template Metaprogrammng. Does anyone have any more insight?

Comment: @Jaywalker: Do you mean specifically for functions or for structs / classes?

Answer (score 9):

`template<>` introduces a total specialization of a template. Your example by itself isn't actually valid; you need a more detailed scenario before it becomes useful:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    // body for the general case
};

template <>
class A<bool>
{
    // body that only applies for T = bool
};

int main()
{
    // ...
    A<int>  ai; // uses the first class definition
    A<bool> ab; // uses the second class definition
    // ...
}
```

It looks strange because it's a special case of a more powerful feature, which is called "partial specialization."

Comment: Explicit (not "total") specialization is not a special case of partial specialization. Explicit specialization defines a class identified by a template-id; partial specialization defines a new template accessed through a primary template.

Comment: I prefer the term "total," because it is opposed by "partial" (which is a thing), whereas "explicit" is opposed by "implicit" (which is not a thing). I'm aware that it's not the standard term.

Syntactically, explicit specialization is a special case of partial specialization, even if the most standards-correct way to look at the two makes a distinction between classes and class templates.

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't look right. Now, you might have instead written:

```
template<>
class A<foo> {
// some stuff
};
```

... which would be a *template specialisation* for type foo.